# In Q Learning, how can you ever actually get a Q value? Wouldn't Q(s,a) just go on forever?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I've been studying up on reinforcement learning, but the thing I don't understand is how a Q value is ever calculated. If you use the Bellman equation `Q(s,a) = r + γ*max(Q(s',a'))`, would't it just go on forever? Because `Q(s',a')` would need the Q value of one timestep further, and that would just continue on and on. How does it end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Reinforcement Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning) you normally try to find a policy (the best action to take in a specific state), and the learning process ends when the policy does not change anymore or the value function (representing the expected reward) has converged.

---

You seem to confuse [Q-learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning) and [Value Iteration using the Bellman equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process#Value_iteration). Q-learning is a model-free technique where you use obtained reward to update *Q*:

[image: Q formula]

Here the direct reward *r<sub>t+1</sub>* is the reward obtained after having done action *a<sub>t</sub>* in state *s<sub>t</sub>*. α is the learning rate that should be between 0 and 1, if it is 0 no learning is done, if it is 1 only the newest reward is taken into account.

[Value iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process#Value_iteration) with the [Bellman equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_equation):

[image: bellman]

Where a model *P<sub>a</sub>(s,s')* is required, also defined as *P(s'|s,a)*, which is the probability of going from state *s* to *s'* using action *a*. To check if the value function is converged, normally the value function *V<sub>t+1</sub>* is compared to  *V<sub>t</sub>* for all states and if it is smaller than a small value (ε) the policy is said to be converged:

[image: converged]

---

See also:

- [Difference between Q-learning and Value Iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937803/difference-between-q-learning-and-value-iteration)
- [How do I know when a Q-learning algorithm converges?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/206944/how-do-i-know-when-a-q-learning-algorithm-converges)
- [Sutton et al.: RL](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/node65.html)